# Highcharts minPadding not applied when zero value in series

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have an issues setting up highcharts 5. I created a [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ar6Lqtvo/) for it.

I want to have the same space under the line graph as above it.

Setting `minPadding` is working for me only when I have no zero based value in series data.

Do you know what I am setting wrong in my chart?

Comment: try this ,give in yaxis  min: -2, 
 max : 5, min  max y axis values

Comment: Well this is possible to set but this is not what i wanted to hardcode. Anyway it is a bit wrong and results in yAxis min -2 and max 6 shown on chart, not -2 and 5.

Comment: yeah, i just gave you a hint.
you can try dynamically, if your series has **0** in it, set min to -2 else set to 0,you have to check your series data,

Comment: or you can find the minimum value from your series and maximum value, and set **min: min_val-2, max:max_val+2**;

Comment: thank you for your hints

Comment: try this way, check max and min for your series `var max_y = Math.max.apply(null,y_array) +2;`

`var min_y = Math.min.apply(null,y_array) -2; `
and pass it to min and max in yaxis param

Comment: You can try to change [series.threshold](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.threshold) property. By default it is 0 - http://jsfiddle.net/ar6Lqtvo/2/ I am not sure if it desired behaviour - if you think it is a bug createa a new ticket on github repo https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues

Comment: Thanks, i ended up setting "series.softThreshold: false" by now.